# Runing a makefile list of target with wait

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I've a make file which runs several of targets , now I want to add new target that will run after some timeout, how can I do it ?

e.g.

`execbin: build start run`

This is running ok, however I want to add new target **called test** which will run after two seconds 
(some timeout) , how can I do that ?

`execbin: build start run test`

`test` should execute after the run has finished and also wait 2 seconds before it start , is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lazy solution would be to add a new target called 'sleep-2', and a pattern rule do:

```
execbin: build start run sleep-2 test

sleep-%:
        sleep $(@:sleep-%=%)
```

This creates a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) that takes the value after the hyphen in a sleep-<> target, and uses it as the amount of time to sleep.

> I will echo @MadScientists's answer that this probably will not work if you do `make -j`, which really does require changing the targets to depend on each other.

Answer (score 4):

Adding more prerequisites to the list relies on make's behavior that it always tries to build prerequisites in order.  While that is a documented requirement of POSIX, so it will always be true, it only works well if you don't use parallelism in your builds (you don't run with `-j`).  If you do, then make can run all of those targets *at the same time*.

If you want to be sure that a given target does not start until another target finishes, the correct way to do it is declare a *prerequisite* relationship between them, not add them to the end of a different target's prerequisite list.

So, for example, if you want the `test` target to not start until the `run` target is complete, you should declare that:

```
test: run
        run my tests
```

Now, `test` cannot be started until `run` is complete.  The simplest way to introduce a sleep is just to put it into the recipe for `test` like this:

```
test: run
        sleep 2
        run my tests
```

If you want to be more fancy and use a separate target then you need to link the prerequisites, like this:

```
test: sleep-2
        run my tests
sleep-2: run
        sleep 2
```

Unless you have lots of these I think the simple way above is easier to understand.